# Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboardV1_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle - in the iOS 5.0 Simulator

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard

I'm getting a strange error that I have never seen before.

I've tested my app under the iOS 6.0 Simulator, everything works fine. But when I switch to iOS 5.0 Simulator, I get the following error when I launch the app

Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboardV1_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle

This occurs at startup.

I've checked the config. MainStoryboardV1_iPhone.storyboard exists and the configure states to use 'MainStoryboardV1_iPhone'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This basically because you are using base localization to translate your storyboard.
And this method only works on iOS 6.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.

I had the storyboard file in a subdirectory. This seems to be fine for iOS 6.0 but fails in iOS 5.0. Moving the storyboard file to the 'root' app directory fixed the problem.

Comment: What was the name of the subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

Also happened to me.

It seems that using ios 6 base localization moves the storyboard file, so ios 5 doesn't find the file. Using english localization instead fixed the issue for me.